# how to find the frequency of the downsampled signal?

Tags: discrete-signals, downsampling

So, I am trying to solve this question.

Consider the signal, $$x=\cos\left(\left(\dfrac{2\pi}{3} \right)n\right)$$

The signal is downsampled by a factor of two. Indicate the frequency of the resulting output, normalized by $2\pi$

(E.g., if the frequency is $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$, write $\dfrac{1}{4}$)

So, what I understood is,

from the signal, $f = \dfrac{1}{N} \implies \dfrac{1}{3}$  or $\dfrac{2\pi}{3}$ if we consider angular frequency.

So after downsampling,
$$f_d = \dfrac{f}{M} = \frac{1}{3}\cdot \frac{1}{2}  \implies \frac{1}{6}$$.

or, if taking $\dfrac{2\pi}{3}$ and downsampling by factor $2$ then, $\dfrac{2\pi}{3}\cdot\dfrac{1}{2} = \dfrac{\pi}{3}$ or $\dfrac{1}{6}$

But the answer is wrong. How should I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the term *downsampling* is used in its correct meaning as *anti-aliasing lowpass filtering* followed by *decimation*, then your output should be zero, as the lowpass filter with a cutoff frequency of $\omega = \pi/2$ should remove the input $x[n] = \cos( \frac{2\pi}{3} n) $ ; i.e. , frequency of the cosine is out of the passband of the lowpass filter, and will be blocked by the filter.

However, if you simply mean *decimation* (or *compression*) by the term downsampling, then, the output will be: $y[n] = x[2n] = \cos(\frac{2\pi}{3} 2n) = \cos(\frac{4\pi}{3} n) = \cos(\frac{2\pi}{3} n) = x[n]$. This equivalence is due to the aliasing that occurs for omitting the anti-aliasing lowpass filter.

Hence, in this case the frequency of the output is the same as frequency of the input.